# Thread safe stack implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14

Reading

> "C++ Concurrency in Action" by Anthony Williams (1st edition)

you can find this implementation for a thread safe stack:

```
struct empty_stack: std::exception
{
    const char* what() const throw()
    {
        return "empty stack";
    }
};  

template<typename T>  
class threadsafe_stack  
{  
    private:
    std::stack<T> data;
    mutable std::mutex m;  
    public:
    threadsafe_stack(){}
    threadsafe_stack(const threadsafe_stack& other)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(other.m);
        data=other.data;
    }
    threadsafe_stack& operator=(const threadsafe_stack&) = delete;

    void push(T new_value)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
        data.push(new_value);
    }
    std::shared_ptr<T> pop()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
        if(data.empty()) throw empty_stack();
        std::shared_ptr<T> const res(std::make_shared<T>(data.top()));
        data.pop();
        return res;
    }
    void pop(T& value)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
        if(data.empty()) throw empty_stack();
        value=data.top();
        data.pop();
    }
    bool empty() const
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
        return data.empty();
    }
};
```

so, discussing the possible implementations, the author proposes the next version for pop():

```
void pop(T& value)  
{  
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);  
    if(data.empty()) throw empty_stack();  
    value=data.top();  
    data.pop();  
}
```

and highlights some caveats and one of these caveats is that this solution requires that the type stored in the stack must be assignable.

At the same time he shows the next example of usage:

```
std::vector<int> result;
some_stack.pop(result);
```

**Now my objection:**
in my opinion another caveat is needed:
the assignment operator of the type stored in the thread safe stack  must not throw exception like assignment operator of std::vector can.

**Is my objection based?**

Reasons for my objection:
it arises from the analysis of the next solution ( not implemented ) proposed by the author:

*"you can write a value-returning pop() if the return by value can not throw an exception, so the types stored in the thread safe stack require a not-throw copy constructor or move constructor"*.

Thank for your time.

Comment: To me it sounds like the caveat you mention is only needed on this other solution, and he did add the caveat when proposing it. Why do you think the caveat is needed even without it?

Comment: @CássioRenan because "value=data.top();" can throw

Comment: On `value=data.top()`, the exception is thrown while we still hold the lock; On the other case, the exception will be thrown after the return from `pop()` (and consequently after the release of the lock). Can't say if that would make any difference, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you feel it's OK to throw `empty_stack`, but not OK to throw whatever the vector's assignment might throw?

The problem with `T pop()` is that it needs to first remove the value from the stack, and then copy it - which might throw, at which point you lose the value; it's neither returned nor left in the container. In other words, such a design cannot provide a [strong exception guarantee](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/exceptions#Exception_safety).

This is why `std::stack` provides two separate calls - `T top()` to read the top without modifying the stack (if that throws, the stack is left intact), and `void pop()` that modifies the stack and is guaranteed not to throw.

Comment: @IgorTandenik: maybe when I call threadsafe_stack::pop(T& value) I have to put it in a try-catch in order to capture a possibile exception threw by the assignment   "value=data.top();" ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you know how to handle the exception, then by all means, catch and handle it. If you don't, don't. No one is forcing you.

Comment: @IgorTandenik: ok, the problem is my poor english and my poor C++. Thanks a lot.